# Find the derivative of $x ^3$ by using the differential quotient

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

Find the derivative of the function $y = f(x) = x
^3$ by using the
differential quotient
$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{x→x_0}
\frac{f(x) − f(x_0)}{x − x_0}.$$

You must use the polynomial division to simplify it.

Ok so by substituting $x^3$, I get $$\lim_{x→x_0}
\frac{x^3 − x_0^3}{x − x_0}.$$

Then I use polynom. div. to get 
$x^2+x \cdot x_0+x_0^2$
but this does not give me the derivative. So it is wrong. I would appreciate some advice.

Edit: Ok so with @coreyman317 's suggestion I believe I have the right answer.
$x^2+x \cdot x_0+x_0^2$

I substitute the limit $x_0$ into the equation and then I get $x_0^2+x_0 \cdot x_0+x_0^2=3x_0^2$
Which is the right answer! Thanks guys!

Comment: Note also that $x^2 + xx_0 + x_0^2$ is continuous at $x = x_0$.

Comment: @coreyman317 that helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It is $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$
and $$x^2+xx_0+x_0^2$$ tends to $$3x_0^2$$

Comment: Still gives me the same answer

Comment: Yeah I didn't know you could substitute the limits. I solved it just now. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I wish you a nice day!

Comment: Thanks! And you too.

Answer (score 0):

Polynomial division:

$\small {(x^3-x_0^3)÷(x-x_0)= x^2 +xx_0+ x_0^2}$.

$\small {-(x^3 -x^2x_0)}$

$-------$

$\small {x^2x_0 -x_0^3}$

$\small{-(x^2x_0 -xx_0^2)}$

$-------$

$\small{xx_0^2-x_0^3}$

$\small{-(xx_0^2-x_0^3)}$

$--------$

$\small{0}$